# Create "rotated" non-buffered grid (Vaadin)

Tags: java, grid, vaadin

I am thinking about the solution of this problem, but I have no idea how to do this:

I have entity `SchoolBook` with this properties:

```
Long id;
String studentName;
Long studentId;
LocalDate day;
String points;
```

`SchoolBook` using data from database, and they looks like:

```
id | studentName |  studentId |   day     | points
----------------------------------------------------
1  |    Adam     |   1000001  | 1.9.2022  |   1
2  |    Adam     |   1000001  | 3.9.2022  |   2
3  |    Adam     |   1000001  | 6.9.2022  |   3
4  |    Marc     |   1000002  | 2.9.2022  |   2
5  |    Marc     |   1000002  | 5.9.2022  |   A
6  |    Marc     |   1000002  | 30.9.2022 |   3
7  |    Fred     |   1000003  | 2.9.2022  |   C
8  |    Fred     |   1000003  | 4.9.2022  |   1
9  |    Fred     |   1000003  | 4.8.2022  |   1
10 |    Adam     |   1000001  | 6.8.2022  |   F
```

The alphabetical characters can be represented in numeric value as

```
A (10 points), B (9 points), C (8 points), D (7 points), E (6 points), F (5 points)
```

Now I would like to do something like this:

[image]

- `column names` in `grid` will be the **names of students**
- first column will have `automaticly generated` days (dates) for selected month
- **"rows"** will have the `points` from `SchoolBook` table - **each for corresponding day**

The **last row** will be something like "sum row" showing the `sum` for **each** student during the `actual month`.

So I have created the `SyntheticRow` class with these properties:

```
Long syntheticRowId;
LocalDate date;
Map<Long, String> map;
```

After this I created the `SyntheticRowService` which creates items for `grid` with these functions:

```
public int getNumberOfDaysInMonth(int month, int year) {
    YearMonth yearMonthObject = YearMonth.of(year, month);
    return yearMonthObject.lengthOfMonth();
}

public List<SyntheticRow> getDataForSpecificMonth(PageRequest of, int month, int year) {

    List<SyntheticRow> syntheticRows = new ArrayList<>();

    int syntheticRowId = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= getNumberOfDaysInMonth(month, year); i++) {
        List<SchoolBook> schoolBooks = repository.findByDay(LocalDate.of(year, month, i));

        for (SchoolBook schoolBook : schoolBooks) {
            SyntheticRow syntheticRow = new SyntheticRow();
            syntheticRow.setDate(LocalDate.of(year, month, i));
            syntheticRow.setSyntheticRowId(Long.valueOf(syntheticRowId));

            Map<Long, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put(schoolBook.getStudentId(), schoolBook.getPoints());

            syntheticRow.setMap(map);
            syntheticRows.add(syntheticRow);
            syntheticRowId++;
        }

    }

    return syntheticRows;
}
```

Now I have `grid` with loaded data:

```
List<Student> students = userService.getAllStudentsFromClass(classId); //function returns all students from class (it contains also students without records in SchoolBook)

grid.setItems(query -> syntheticRowService.getDataForSpecificMonth(PageRequest.of(query.getPage(), query.getPageSize(), VaadinSpringDataHelpers.toSpringDataSort(query)),9,2022).stream());
grid.addColumn(SyntheticRow::getDate).setHeader("Date");

for (Student student : students) {
    grid.addColumn(syntheticRow -> syntheticRow.getMap().get(student.getStudentId())).setHeader(student.getStudentName() + " (" + student.getStudentId() + ")");
}
```

Now I get this result:

[image]

The problem now is, that I have data in **multiple rows**, not only in one, for specific day.

E.g. date `2022-09-23`, or date `2022-09-19`.

So the data `should be` in one row and divided into the specified column for `studentName/studentId`. And some dates are missing - like 2022-09-14, 2022-09-15, 2022-09-16.

Solution:

```
public List<SyntheticRow> getDataForSpecificMonth(PageRequest of, int month, int year) {

    List<SyntheticRow> syntheticRows = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= getNumberOfDaysInMonth(month, year); i++) {
        List<SchoolBook> schoolBooks = repository.findByDay(LocalDate.of(year, month, i));

        SyntheticRow syntheticRow = new SyntheticRow();
        Map<Long, String> map = new HashMap<>();

        schoolBooks.setDate(LocalDate.of(year, month, i));

        if(!schoolBooks.isEmpty()) {
            for (SchoolBook schoolBook : schoolBooks) {
                map.put(schoolBook.getStudentId(), schoolBook.getPoints());
            }
        }

        syntheticRow.setMap(map);
        syntheticRows.add(syntheticRow);
    }

    return syntheticRows;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group your data by date, then by student.  Create a synthetic row class,
that has a date and a map from student to points.  Make the grid using
this row class.  Add the date column and then add for each student
a column, that extracts the score by student from the map in the row.

If you don't know all students beforehand, build a (sorted) set from the
original data or the union of the key-sets of all row's student maps.

Assuming, that your data is most likely sparse and roughly 30x30, you can do
this eagerly.  If your database can already provide a [pivot view](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table) of the
data, use that directly.

Comment: How do you think this part: "group your data by date, then by student". In database? Or where ? what should they look like then?

Comment: @Andromeda In your code - grouping in the DB won't do you any good, unless your
DB is able to build the whole pivot result. I'd not bend over backwards to make
it work with the DB if it's not already there

Comment: Mr. @cfrick please check my edited post. And thank you for ideas!

Comment: @Andromeda: first, you need to add the columns for the student dynamically (use `addColumn` with a getter, iterate over all known students to add a column); next using the DTO as key for the map feels sketchy; use the id of the student (or anything else that allows you to look up a student reliably) - in your example data, this is `studentName`, but this is obviously a bad idea, because different students can have the same name -- but to get going, you could start with it.

Comment: Mr. @cfrick so I added the `studentId` to the `SchoolBook` and change the Map from `Map<Schoolbook, String>` to `Map<Long, String>`  where `Long`  part defines the `studentId` setted in function `createMapsForSpecificDay`. Then I have created columns for all students from class, but the every column contains data for each students, not only for corresponding `student`.

Comment: @Andromeda why do you have a list of maps? For each student, add the column and use the getter to read the **grade** for **that** student.  The map must from student to grade so you can easily look it up.

Comment: And of course thanks for all the information so far.